# Not able to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows on Dynamic Disk

Tags: dual-boot

I have 2 disks in my machine - SSD (Basic) with windows 10 on it and HDD (Dynamic) with 2 Partitions and 58 GB Free Space. I had created this 58GB Free Space using windows 10 Shrink Volume feature.
[image: Windows 10 Disk Management]

When i try to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dynamic Disk, I do not see free space created in windows. I just see a single /dev/sda1 with no free space/ other partitions at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dynamic disks and partitions by Windows do not work with linux

You should leave the drive space when you shrink Windows partitions as unallocated space, reboot from an Ubuntu install drive and use gparted to create partitions and file systems for Ubuntu.

Comment: So, i can not install Ubuntu on Disk 0 (refer to my screenshot with question) since it is a Dynamic Partition? Or creating unallocated space on Disk 0 will help? I tried Gparted but it did not show any partition/unallocated space in Disk 0.

Comment: I think so. Dynamic partitioning is a proprietary system/method of Microsoft, and you must use a different partition system/method for linux. This is possible, but all data in the drive will be lost. So if this is what you want, you must copy the content of the NTFS partitions 'data' and 'backup' to another drive. (Or maybe get another drive for linux, and create a partition table and partitions with gparted on this new drive). If this is not what you want, you can install *VirtualBox* in Windows and install *Ubuntu in a virtual machine* of VirtualBox.

Comment: I could not edit the previous comment.I hope this is explaining better: I think It is *impossible* to use a Microsoft Dynamic Disk or a Microsoft Dynamic Partition for linux, and Ubuntu is a linux operating system. But you can run Ubuntu in VirtualBox (inside Windows).