# transfer windows 7 files/folders permanently

Tags: usb

Can I transfer files/folders permanently from Windows 7 if I use a usb or Seagate to load them and then install them from that into Ubuntu? I don't want to access Windows at all anymore and I would like the convenience of having my files directly in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can also do this without external media. Ubuntu (Linux in general) will happily mount your windows system if it is clean and lets you copy files from it to another partition.

Mind that with moving files I expect you to move video, audio, word, excel files and the like. Though you can copy executable files (ie. .exe or .bat) that those will not run in Ubuntu. The same goes for anything that hold visual basic.

Comment: Yesterday I did attempt to mount Windows. It seemed to work but when I accessed where they're stored I can't read the file/folders. Most have a code under them. One of them does say "Documents and Settings" and has a small curved arrow as if an open option.I haven't tried to click on it. Also when I boot into Ubuntu the Dock OS icon disappears. I have tried to permanently mount Windows a few times, but it always does this.

Comment: also a thing to consider: use sudo to make the files owned by you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

If you launch Disk Management (right click on [START] icon then choose Disk Management) check the drive to see if it is [a Dynamic Disk or a Basic Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks). Basic Disks can be read from and written to by Ubuntu; [Dynamic Disks cannot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864351/not-able-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-windows-on-dynamic-disk).

Have a Basic Disk? Good. Your Documents and Settings files are [actually mostly in or under](https://4sysops.com/archives/documents-and-settings-in-vista/) C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\ with the remainder in or under C:\Users\%user name%\AppData\Roaming\ .